# send message not reaching the handler in activity

Tags: android

I am having the service and activity. inside service i am sending the message.
I am trying to catch it inside the main activity. But message is not reaching the handler in activity.

Please see the code below.

Service:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(112345);
```

MainActivity:

```
handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "handled message successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if ( msg.what == 1234 ) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "handled message successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not reaching the handler in the activity.
As far as i know

Comment: Do the Service and the Activity run in the same process?

Comment: Also, does the code snippet of the Activity run on the main UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

All messages you are sending using `Handler.sendMessageXXX` will be handled by the same `Handler` object. So you have to pass the `Handler` from `Activity` to `Service`. It can be done using `Messenger` class.

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "handleMessage " + msg.what, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);

        intent.putExtra("messenger", messenger);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService() {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final Messenger messenger = (Messenger) intent.getParcelableExtra("messenger");
        final Message message = Message.obtain(null, 1234);


        try {
            messenger.send(message);
        } catch (RemoteException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```