# Call class from method in java

Tags: java, android

I have a method written in a main thread(UI thraed) in android service. In tht method I created a handler class like below

```
public void myMethod(){
        public Handler _handler = new Handler(){

            public void handleMessage(Message msg){

                         Log.v("LOG_TAG", "value of msg===>"+msg);
              }

   };
```

My question is how to call _handler object in another thread so that I can get data to handler class.

Thanks

Comment: public variable inside a method in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 public void myMethod(){
            Handler _handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){

                public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                             // Call your method of UI thread here... it will work.
                             Toast.makeText(context, "UI test", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
                             Log.v("LOG_TAG", "value of msg===>"+msg);
                  }

       };
       _handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
   }
```

and one more alternative:

```
public void myMethod(){
             Handler _handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
             _handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     // Call your method of UI thread here... it will work.
                     Toast.makeText(context, "UI test", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();                         
             });
}
```

and if you not able to call your ui methods inside myMethod (not in scope) then see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444110/3582473

Comment: I want to pass data from worker thread to myMethod() .ie main thread. If i use above thing how to pass data from worker thraed to above method